# Syntax error EOF occurs when binding from xaml namespace

Tags: xaml, uwp

I tried to compiled binding `Datacontext` with my viewmodel. Yes, there are numerous ways to do that, but I find it interesting that doing this particular method

```
<Page
    ...
    x:Class="Random.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns:vm="using:Random.ViewModels"
    DataContext="{x:Bind vm:MainViewModel}">
```

returns an error

```
Invalid binding path 'vm:MainViewModel' : Syntax error at symbol '<EOF>'
```

yet it considers a valid code in visual studio v15.9.8.
Is this a x:Bind parse error or unintended practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) . But `vm:MainViewModel` is not property on your data source.

> At XAML compile time, {x:Bind} is converted into code that will get a value from a **property** on a data source, and set it on the property specified in markup.

For your requirement, you could set page `DataContext` like the folliwing.

```
<Page
    x:Class="PivotItemTest.MainPage"    
    ......   
    xmlns:vm="using:PivotItemTest.ViewModels">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
    </Page.DataContext>
```